# How to explain unexpected output from L293D?

Tags: voltage-regulator, motor-controller

I have configured an L293D IC along with a PIC MCU to control a 9V DC motor via PWM.  The schematic is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVxHZK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For an input 1A = +5V and 2A = 0V, and a clean PWM signal at 1.2 kHz, I am getting the following output across pins 3 and 6 of the L293D:

[image]

Is this expected?  And if not, what am I getting wrong?

EDIT: I should point out that the signal was tested with no load.

Comment: Was a motor attached when you captured your oscillogram?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that, just edited

Comment: But when I subsequently attached a motor, it did not spin

Answer (score 0):

Pin 1 is the enable/disable input for channels 1 and 2: -

[image]

Pin 1 enables and disables Ch1 and Ch2 at 1.2 kHz (MCU PWM). When disabled, channel outputs go into a high-impedance state and therefore, your scope picture seems very reasonable: -

[image]

Comment: OK, comment taken on board.  But I thought I'd understand that (at least one of) the benefit of using a motor driver was that it was possible to pass PWM to the enable pin to regulate speed, and control on/off forward/reverse via the input pins ... like here: https://deepbluembedded.com/dc-motor-speed-control-l293d-motor-driver/.  I was wondering whether there was an issue with the targeted frequency versus the amount of capacitance in the circuit.

Comment: @RickyBoy if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. It's got nothing to do with capacitance nor can I make head nor tail of the link you left. BTW I don't watch videos so, if you are not satisfied with my answer (not a comment) then please wait until someone else leaves an answer.